# Why isn't my elastic search query returning the text analyzed by english analyzer?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index named `test_blocks`

```
{
  "test_blocks" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "block" : {
        "dynamic" : "false",
        "properties" : {
          "content" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "content_en" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "english"
              }
            }
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "title_en" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "english"
              }
            }
          },
          "user_id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1438642440687",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "1070099"
        },
        "uuid" : "45vkIigXSCyvHN6g-w5kkg"
      }
    },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

When I do a search for `killing`, a word in the content, the search results return as expected.

```
http://localhost:9200/test_blocks/_search?q=killing&pretty=1


{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.07431685,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "test_blocks",
      "_type" : "block",
      "_id" : "218",
      "_score" : 0.07431685,
      "_source":{"block":{"id":218,"title":"The \u003ci\u003eparticle\u003c/i\u003e streak","content":"Barry Allen is a Central City police forensic scientist\n                        with a reasonably happy life, despite the childhood\n                        trauma of a mysterious red and yellow being killing his\n                        mother and framing his father. All that changes when a\n                        massive \u003cb\u003eparticle\u003c/b\u003e accelerator accident leads to Barry\n                        being struck by lightning in his lab.","user_id":82}}
    }, {
      "_index" : "test_blocks",
      "_type" : "block",
      "_id" : "219",
      "_score" : 0.07431685,
      "_source":{"block":{"id":219,"title":"The \u003ci\u003eparticle\u003c/i\u003e streak","content":"Barry Allen is a Central City police forensic scientist\n                        with a reasonably happy life, despite the childhood\n                        trauma of a mysterious red and yellow being killing his\n                        mother and framing his father. All that changes when a\n                        massive \u003cb\u003eparticle\u003c/b\u003e accelerator accident leads to Barry\n                        being struck by lightning in his lab.","user_id":83}}
    } ]
  }
}
```

However given that I have an `english` analyzer for the content field **(content_en)**, I would have expected it to return me the same document for the query `kill`. But it doesn't. I get 0 hits.

```
http://localhost:9200/test_blocks/_search?q=kill&pretty=1

{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

My understanding through this analyze query is that "killing" would have got broken down in to "kill"

```
http://localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=english&text=killing

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "kill",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

So why isn't the query "kill" match that document ? Are my mappings incorrect or is it my search that is incorrect?

I am using elasticsearch v1.7.0

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `fuzzysearch` (some introduction available [here](https://www.found.no/foundation/fuzzy-search/)):

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test_blocks/_search' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "kill",
        "fuzziness": 2,
        "prefix_length": 1
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**UPD**. Having `content_en` field with content which was given by stemmer, it makes sense to actually query that field:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test_blocks/_search' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type": "most_fields",
      "query": "kill",
      "fields": ["block.title", "block.title.title_en"]
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: But the english analyzer I use already has a stemmer built in which should have changed killing to kill. Is that an incorrect assumption ?

Comment: Ah, you are right. Updated my answer with an example of request which would actually use the field your stemmer uses.

Comment: I tested with `"fields": ["title", "title.title_en", "content", "content.content_en"]` but still no hits. Anything else I am doing wrong ? Anything else I should be looking at?

Comment: The same query definitely works on my schema. Please tell me, if you use 'killing' instead of kill in last query I suggested, does it return the record?

Comment: @RanhiruCooray I just payed attention that your object is a hash with 'block' key. So, fields should be ["block.content", "block.content.content_en"].

Comment: Hey, I've tried both combinations but I am unable to make it work. It works for `http://localhost:9200/_search?q=killing` but not `http://localhost:9200/_search?q=kill`.

Answer (score 1):

The following queries `http://localhost:9200/_search?q=kill.` ,`http://localhost:9200/_search?q=kill.` end up searching across 
_all field .

[_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-all-field.html) field uses the default analyzer which unless overridden happens to be *standard analyzer* and not *english analyzer* .

For making the above query work you would need to add english analyzer to *_all* field and re-index 
Example:

```
    {
      "mappings": {
        "block": {
            "_all" : {"analyzer" : "english"}
       }
   }
```

Also would point out the mapping in OP doesn't seem consistent with the document structure. As @EugZol pointed our the content is within *block object* so the mapping should be something on these lines :

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "block": {
      "properties": {
        "block": {
          "properties": {
            "content": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "standard",
              "fields": {
                "content_en": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "english"
                }
              }
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "standard",
              "fields": {
                "title_en": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "english"
                }
              }
            },
            "user_id": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply keety. That makes perfect sense that it uses `_all`. The document structure was generated through elasticsearch-rails gem. I haven't specified 'dynamic: false' option and that ended up making the structure look like that. I have updated the mapping. Please take a look. But now, even 'killing' isn't returning any hits. While `http://localhost:9200/test_blocks/_search?pretty=1` returns the documents with the contents, `http://localhost:9200/test_blocks/_search?q=killing&pretty=1` gets no hits. That's a term directly there. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @RanhiruCooray based on the OP document structure looks like  *_source":{"block":{"id":219,"title":"The "}* in which case the mapping in OP  not correct. The mapping requires to have  a *block* object within *block* type as in the answer. The reason you don't get any results is because dynamic is false and the document does not conform to the mapping so the fields in documents are not indexed just stored .

Comment: Also once you fix the mapping you need to run the query   **localhost:9200/test_blocks?q=block.content.content_en%3Akill&pretty=1** i.e query vs the *block.content.content_en* field and not *_all* field

Comment: Thanks a lot. The issue turned out to be how I was indexing the data. I found out that the data was not properly sent to be indexed through the `head` plugin.